# Imacros Error -1000: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component with long variable

Tags: imacros

I am using this code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:download_url EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR6 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL 
URL GOTO={{!VAR6}}
```

When `!VAR6` is a long URL, I get this error

```
Error -1000: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.. Line 27: URL GOTO={{!VAR6}}
```

There is no error if the `!VAR6` is a short URL.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.imacros.net/Error_and_Return_Codes

```
Code     Reason
-1000   Unspecified: Macro playback returned an error without explicitly specifying an error code.
```

Try this out.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:download_url EXTRACT=HREF
SET !VAR6 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL 
URL GOTO={{!VAR6}}
```

I replaced EXTRACT=TXT with EXTRACT=HREF .